# Why is the product of the two output from one system and its inverse not equal to 1?

Tags: matlab, vector, filter, signals

I used filter() function in Matlab to simulate a system and its inverse. However, when I was trying to verify that the inverse system works the way it should, I found that H(z)H_i(Z) is not equal to 1, which does not agree with the property of the inverse system. Here is my code:

```
function y2 = Inverse()

b = [2 0 0.5];
a = [1 0 -0.25];

fprintf('2y(n)+0.5y(n-2) = x(n)-0.25x(n-2)\n')
N = 30 ;
n =[0: N-1] ;
x = 0.8.^n;

y = filter(b,a,x);
subplot(3,2,1);stem(x,y);

y1 = filter(a,b,x);
subplot(3,2,2);stem(x,y1);

y2 = y.*y1;
end
```

In my opinion, y2 should be a vector of all ones. Did I make any mistakes in my code or misunderstand the inverse system?

Comment: At no point are you calculating `H(z)*H_i(Z)`, you are multiplying the outputs of the filters, not the filters. There is an entire field of measure theory behind this, among other things the Fourier transform, Z-transform etc. Its a bit rusty for me, but AFAIK you can not just multiply things as you want, operations are not the same in fourier space than they are in signal-space

Comment: Thank you. It seems that I have got the usage of filter() wrong.

Answer (score 0):

filter() function filters the input data -in your case "x"- w.r.t the filter coefficients you provide, "b" and "a". Although there may be some merit in interpreting systems like filters -control systems act as lowpass filters for that matter- inspecting them via the filter() function is not valid. What you're trying to see can be seen in the following code:

```
num = [2 0 0.5];
den = [1 0 -0.25];

sys    = tf(num, den);
invSys = inv(sys);

prod = sys*invSys
gain = minreal(prod)

>>

prod =
 
  2 s^4 - 0.125
  -------------
  2 s^4 - 0.125
 
Continuous-time transfer function.


gain =
 
  1
 
Static gain.
```

As you can see, the product of the inverse and the actual system yields an identical pair of numerator and denominator. The minimum realization of such a system gives 1, as you would expect.

You could use the system "sys" as a filter but beware that it is open-loop unstable. If you want to mess around with filters, the digital filter designer tool of Simulink has a great visual interface, and you can export the filter coefficients to the workspace so that you can use them with filter:

```
filter(exported_num, exported_den, noisyData);
```